# Consume SSRS 2008R2 x64 report from ASP.NET app using Oracle ODAC11.2.0.1.0 on IIS 7.5 (Enabled 32 bit apps) on Win7 x64

Tags: asp.net, oracle, reporting-services, iis-7.5, 32bit-64bit

On my development machine (Win7 x64, IIS 7.5, SSRS 2008R2 x64), I have an ASP.Net app (application pool with "Enable 32-bit apps" set to "True") connecting to an Oracle database server, using Oracle Data Provider for .Net 32 bits (ODAC 11.2.0.1.0, Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.0.).
IIS 7.5 and SSRS 2008 R2 run on the same development machine.
Oracle runs on a test server.

It works fine, except when I embed a report from SSRS 2008 R2, using ReportViewer, like this:

```
    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
    reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = New ReportServerCredentials()
    Dim serverReport As ServerReport
    serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport
    serverReport.ReportPath = "/" + ReportServerCredentials.ReportFolder + "/rptParteIngreso"
    serverReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri(ReportServerCredentials.urlServerReporting)
    Dim parameters() As ReportParameter = {P_IDPAIS, P_FECHAINICIO, P_FECHAFIN, P_NROPARTE, P_FLAGAPROBING}

    Try
        serverReport.SetParameters(parameters)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBoxs.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString())
    End Try
```

It throws the following error:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=rsProcessingAborted
  Message=Error al procesar el informe. (rsProcessingAborted)
  Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
  StackTrace:
       en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
       en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
       en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetExecutionParameters(ParameterValue[] Parameters, String ParameterLanguage)
       en Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
.....
       en System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       en System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       en System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
       ErrorCode=rsErrorOpeningConnection
       Message=Cannot create a connection to data source 'DSRRHH'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
       InnerException: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException
            Message=El intento de cargar las bibliotecas de clientes de Oracle lanzó BadImageFormatException. **Este problema ocurrirá al ejecutar el modo 64 bits con los componente cliente de Oracle de 32 bits instalados**.
            InnerException: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException
                 Message=Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

The relevant message I think is "**This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.**"

Also, on the Task Manager, I've checked Reporting Services is running as a 64-bit process(ReportingServicesService.exe) and my app is running on 32 bits (w3wp.exe *32).

However, when designing the report, it works OK, using ".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle", which I think is provided by Microsoft.

So, my conclusion is there's a conflict between my ASP.Net app (running as 32-bit) and my reports published on a SSRS 2008 R2 x64 server.

So, my question is, how can I embed those SSRS reports in my ASP.Net app?

Some alternatives I've thought:

1. Diable "Enable 32-bit apps" on application pool on IIS, so it will run as 64-bits.
2. Change SSRS process to run as 32-bits. (Is this even posible?)

Also, I've published the reports to another server (SSRS 2008 R2 x64 on Win 2008 R2 x64) and I can embed them without any problem from my ASP.Net 32-bits app on my development machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: Solved. Installed Oracle Data Provider for .Net 64 bits (ODAC 11.2.0.1.0, Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.0.) and disabled "Enable 32-bit apps" on application pool on IIS, so it will run as 64-bits. This way, it can connects to SSRS 2008 R2 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Installed Oracle Data Provider for .Net 64 bits (ODAC 11.2.0.1.0, Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.0.) and disabled "Enable 32-bit apps" on application pool on IIS, so it will run as 64-bits.

This way, it can connects to SSRS 2008 R2 64 bits